# ooVoo URL Schema on iPhone

Tags: iphone, url-scheme

Anyone know if there's a URL schema for the ooVoo iPhone app?

For example, I'm able to launch the Skype app from my app using "skype:userName?call", but there doesn't appear to be an "oovoo:" URL tag.  Did they simply forget to register their custom schema in the app?  Or is it possibly named something different?

The following format in an href appears to be valid for the PC version "oovoo:?call?userName" while I was doing some digging, but doesn't work on the iPhone (the ooVoo app never launches).  I tested the oovoo: tag from a webpage as well, and Safari just reports the address as invalid.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try something more general like oovoo://www.google.com.
If you have ooVoo installed, and Safari cannot recognize the scheme, it doesn't exist.
The specific arguments and variables shouldn't matter until you get into the app.

Comment: Same thing with the more general URL.  They either called the tag something other than oovoo:, or they just never registered it in their app (more likely, can't imagine them "not" naming the tag oovoo).  Thanks.